# Twilio create call - posting params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am trying to initial a call with a custom variable.

As twilio states, `the call is initiated by making a post request to the url provided`

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.calls.create({
    url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to: "+14155551212",
    from: "+1544444444"
}, function(err, call) {
    process.stdout.write(call.sid);
});
```

if the file `voice.xml` has a variable `{{firstName}}`

how do I post `body.firstName`? and whats the appropriate way to format that on the xml side? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you need to pass information via that URL, you can do so as URL parameters. For example:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.calls.create({
    url: "http://example.com/voice.xml&firstName=Phil",
    to: "+14155551212",
    from: "+1544444444"
}, function(err, call) {
    process.stdout.write(call.sid);
});
```

Then, when you handle that [incoming POST request from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request), you can retrieve the URL parameter yourself. If you were using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) as a server, it would look a bit like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var twilio = require('twilio');

var app = new express();

app.post('/voice.xml', function(request, response) {
  var firstName = request.query.firstName;
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  twiml.say('Hello ' + firstName + '! How are you today?';
  response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.